# how can resolve a cyclic redundancy check sql

Tags: sql-server, windows

i need to restore a database but i have a strong problem, please look the photo, is a strange error, please helpme
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately your backup file appears to be corrupt. You could retry and see if it was a transient error or you could use another backup file. Failing that if you run the restore through TSQL you could add WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR and see if it is possible to bypass the problem (this is unlikely unfortunately - but sometimes something is better than nothing).